# Error in variable.summary(gp$pf, dl, nrow(mf)) with gam function from mgcv package in r

Tags: r, mgcv

I am writing a loop to creat multiple model with gam function from mgcv package, but an error occur. I thought it is dataset that make the error occur cause in *dataset2* the code can run, but not in *dataset1*. I do not know how to slove it.

I have upload my dataset to github.

dataset1 :https://github.com/lizhiwei1994/testRepo/blob/master/dataset.csv

dataset2 :https://github.com/lizhiwei1994/testRepo/blob/master/dataset2.csv

this is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)


dat <- dataset1

for(i in 1:6){


  gam.model <- gam(confirm~ dat[, i], data = dat, family =poisson, na.rm=T)
}


# check where the error occur

 # model 1  CAN NOT RUN
i = 1
gam.model.2 <- gam(confirm~ dat[, i], data = dat, family =poisson, na.rm=T)

 # model 2 CAN RUN

gam.model.2 <- gam(confirm~ air1, data = dat, family =poisson, na.rm=T)


# How can I make model 1 run ?




# same model with another dataset

dat2 <- dataset2
for(i in 1:6){


  gam.model <- gam(confirm~ dat2[, i+1], data = dat2, family =poisson, na.rm=T)
}

# model 1 CAN RUN
i = 1
gam.model.1 <- gam(confirm~ dat2[, i+1], data = dat2, family =poisson, na.rm=T)

#model 2 CAN RUN
gam.model.2 <- gam(confirm~ CO, data = dat2, family =poisson, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: What is the error message? Why are you fitting a GAM without smoothers?

Comment: @Roland Message is :Error in variable.summary(gp$pf, dl, nrow(mf)) : Objects cannot be changed to a 'double' type. This a just a simplified model so that I remove the smoothers.

Comment: Strongly suggest to use an alternative approach, like this: `eval(substitute(gam.model.2 <- gam(confirm ~ x, data = dat , family =poisson, na.rm=T), list(x = as.name(names(dat)[i]))))`

Comment: @Roland Thanks a lot! It really helps me.